# Android CPU info under /sys/devices/system/cpu

Tags: android, performance, cpu

I want to look into android CPU perf and became curious over this:

why under `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/` there are these information:

```
cpufreq/   online     rq-stats/  topology/  
cpuidle/   power/     subsystem/ uevent
```

but under `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/` or cpu2, cpu3 directory, there are only these info:

```
cpuidle/   online     power/     subsystem/ uevent
```

I would imagine each directory (cpu0-3) represent each core. But why are there no information about, for example cpu frequency, for cpu1-3 ?

Answer (score 1):

You just list the answer---`cpufreq/`, open it, and you'll see

```
cpuinfo_max_freq
```

In some devices, there is only one `cpuinfo_max_freq` file.

Otherwise, compare them, and take the max.